# Twirl template behind proxy - avoid caching

Tags: caching, playframework, proxy, twirl

I'm running PlayFramework 2.5.x server outside in some cloud provider. Landing page has this detail:

```
    @(webJarAssets: WebJarAssets, form: Form[(String,String,String)], user: Option[User]=None)(implicit flash: Flash, messages: Messages)
....

        @if(user.isDefined){
                       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> @{user.get.firstName} <b class="caret"></b></a>
        }
```

Basically twirl is used to show logged user his name is somewhere in Menu

But problem is that company proxy is caching this front page so everyone from company accessing that page gets last logged firstname (looks like that user is logged in server). F5 helps ( but i'm looking for some better solution)

Strange thing is that in some extent proxy is communicating with Play server because in log when this cached serving is happening this is logged in play server log:

```
2017-01-12 16:55:31  application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-138 [DEBUG] a.s.impl.io.InputStreamPublisher application-akka.stream.default-blocking-io-dispatcher-144 - No more bytes available to read (got `-1` from `read`)
```

As if proxy is asking Play server is this ok? HTTP meta of page looks like this:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Pressing F5 goes to server and gets normal content( but i supose this is proxy-s fault). Anybody had experience with this problem ?